# Lua <eof> expected near 'print'

Tags: lua, eof, zerobrane

I'm having trouble with  in lua.

**Problem one:**
Every time I run the following program the console tells me:

> 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 1) near 'local'

Please notice where I've marked in all caps comments details about the error

```
function m11()
    local inst = mc.mcGetInstance() -- controller instance
    local gcodeLineNbr = mc.mcCntlGetGcodeLineNbr(inst) -- get current Gcode line number
    local gcodeLineStr = mc.mcCntlGetGcodeLine(inst, gcodeLineNbr)  -- get current Gcode line


    function valFromLine(string, axis)
        local startPoint = string.find(string, axis) + 1
        local outputVal = ""
        local isNum = true
        while isNum do
            local num = string.sub(string, startPoint, startPoint)
            startPoint = startPoint + 1
            if num ~= " " then
                outputVal = outputVal .. num
            else
                isNum = false
            end
        end
        outputVal = tonumber(outputVal)
    end
    return outputVal

    --COMPILER HIGHLIGHTS FOLLOWING LINE AS LOCATION OF ERROR
    local gcodeLocX = valFromLine(gcodeLineStr, "X")
    local curLocX = mc.mcAxisGetPos(inst, 0)        -- get current X axis value
    local curLocY = mc.mcAxisGetPos(inst, 1)        -- get current Y axis value
    local curLocZ = mc.mcAxisGetPos(inst, 2)        -- get current Z axis value
    local curAngB = mc.mcAxisGetPos(inst, 4)        -- get current C axis value
    local curAngC = mc.mcAxisGetPos(inst, 5)        -- get current C axis value
    local toolOffset = mc.mcCntlGetToolOffset(inst, 2)  -- get tool offset for axis Z

    function rotateToolB()
        local comHypot = toolOffset * math.sin(angle)       -- get XY planar dist from C pivot to tool centre point
        local compDestinX = comHypot * math.sin(math.rad(90) - curAxisC + curLocX
    end
end
--END OF M11() FUNCTION SHOULD BE HERE

if (mc.mcInEditor() == 1) then
    m11()
end
```

I can't see why it's expecting m11() to close so early.

**Problem two:**
I rewrote valFromLine() in a completely separate file and I get:

> 'eof' expected near 'print'

```
function valFromLine(string, axis)
    local startPoint = string.find(string, axis) + 1
    local outputVal = ""
    local isNum = true
    while isNum do
        local num = string.sub(string, startPoint, startPoint)
        startPoint = startPoint + 1
        if num ~= " " then
            outputVal = outputVal .. num
        else
            isNum = false
        end
    end
  outputVal = tonumber(outputVal)
end
return outputVal

print(valFromLine("GO1 X254.348 Y1039.456 Z150.13 B90.23 C13 M11", "X"))
```

I've counted my 'end' statements, I can't find what's wrong with them in either examples of code. I'm at a complete loss for ideas at this point, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `return outputVal` is at the wrong position. Move it into the function valFromLine.
You cannot return outside the function.

correct:

```
function someFunction()
  -- do something
  local something = "something"
  return something
end
```

wrong:

```
function someFunction()
  -- do something
  local something = "something"
end
return something
```

Defining global functions withn a function is also not very clean, use locals.

Comment: Don't forget it has to be the **last** thing in the function.

Comment: You _can_ return from outside of a function. Or, more accurately, you can't get outside of a function, because "files" in Lua are implicitly vararg functions. The actual error that you can't have more statements after a `return` statement, so the `print` line fails.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I wrote "the" function. Sorry if that was not precise enough. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: That worked thanks warspyking. I thought that my placement was correct because I was referencing an API guide for a program, it shows an example where 'return' is written after 'end'. As you might guess I've just starting learning Lua for this project. Thanks, again.